# CListCtrl OnHdnItemchanging MFC C++ and H Scrollbar

Tags: c++, mfc, notifications, scrollbar, clistctrl

I derived a class from CListCtrl so I can add edititing of every cell sort of like spreadsheet for a database. It all works fine until I added functions to change the RECT of the Cedit Control if the column header was being changed. I put the func in OnHdnItemchanging notification. Again it works perfectly and resizes the CEdit while the colmn width is changed. OKay now the problem. Overriding the OnHdnItemchanging notification now prevents the H Scrollbar from showing up if a column is resized large enough to force the table off page.

Comment: you may have to override OnHScroll method : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787527(v=vs.85).aspx#scroll_bar_visibility

Comment: Won't OnHScroll only be called if the scroll bar is used? If the scrollbar is not showing up at all because of overriding OnHdnItemchanging the OnHScroll notification probably won't be called.

Comment: You can override OnScroll( http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ahzkhw3h(v=vs.80).aspx ) to specify the system when the scrolling must appear.

Comment: OK using ShowScrollBar at end of function does work but how can I determine if the last column is off screen as which I would require the HScrollbar. I wouldn't want to show it if it is not required.

Comment: I suppose I could compare the last columns rect to the clistctrls rect to decide if to show or not. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though,didn't even think about using showscrollbars until I checked out your first link.

Comment: This is how I solved the problem. OnHdnBegintrack I hide the Edit control on OnHdnEndtrack I reshow the edit control resized to the new width and no problem with the scrollbar appearing or hiding automatically.